# Preserve objects when saving image using FastStone Capture Image Editor

Tags: image-editing, faststone-capture

The FastStone Capture Image Editor ("FastStone Draw") allows you to annotate images with arrows, text, shapes etc. All these objects remain as vector-type objects and can be moved, resized, etc. You can close/open the "Draw" part of the editor and all the objects are retained, allowing further adjustment.

However, as soon as you save the image, it is "flattened" into a single raster image. (Even whilst the image is still open in the editor.)

Is there any way to save/export the image in a format that preserves all the annotation objects for later editing?

[image: Image in FastStone Image Editor with Annotations]

The only "Save As" options are BMP, GIF, JPEG, PCX, PNG, TGA, TIFF and PDF. (All but the PDF format can be opened.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This missing feature has finally been added in FastStone Capture version 9.7 (September 10, 2021):

> - Introduced a new image format called FastStone Capture format (*.fsc). This loss-less format preserves annotation objects together with image data for future re-editing

Source: https://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm

(I've tried it and it seems to work well!)